# How to normalize data using Interquartile range?

Tags: normalization, range, interquartile

I am trying to normalize a dataset using the Interquartile range (IQR), I've already gotten the value of IQR, which is Q3 -Q1 (difference between 75th and 25th percentiles), what should I do then?
For example, if I got the next set of data:

0.644
0.666
0.694
0.728
1.487
1.512
1.524
1.665
1.698
1.746
1.859

where Q3= 1.682, Q1= 0.711, so IQR= 0.970.
How can I normalize the values of the set using the IQR value?

Comment: "normalize a dataset" = bring it to standardized scores (z-scores)?

Comment: I've seen people use (value $-$ median) / IQR as a way to put variables on the same (dimensionless and unit-free) scale in the sense that median is then 0 and IQR is 1. In my view, the term "normalize" is always inferior to a precise definition of how values are scaled. Value/IQR could also be used to get a different dimensionless and unit-free scale. There is always a prior question of why do you think this is needed, or even helpful?

Comment: This "(value −− median) / IQR" isn't very good as there's no guarantee for the medain and mean to converge. Moreover, for data $x_i\sim~N(0,1)$ the IQR is 1.349 and thus you can't really get the std.dev size.

Comment: @Spätzle When (value $-$ median) / IQR is used the main point is that (value $-$ mean) / SD would work badly because mean and SD are -- for the data in hand -- so unstable and not especially useful as summaries. So, the former is not usually intended as an approximation to the latter, merely as a quite different alternative. What anyone wants to call "normalize" is entirely up to them and need have no connection or relation to a normal or Gaussian reference distribution. (Above all, just rescaling to mean 0 and SD 1 won't make a distribution closer to normal.)

Comment: @NickCox When (value −− median) / IQR is used, CLT doesn't hold so I wonder what good does it make.

Comment: It is, or it would be, rough-and-ready, practical data analysis at most. I don't think the CLT is even relevant to standardisation in terms of mean and SD; that's nothing more than getting different variables on the same scale.

Comment: What is the practical meaning of the sentence "$x_i$ is 2.3 IQRs over the median"? How does it compare to the practical meaning of "$x_i$ is 3 stdevs over the mean"?

Comment: @Spätzle They're just different scales. If one seems "practical" and the other not, why is that? Whether you're accustomed to thinking on a particular scale has nothing to do with what it means.

Comment: So you're suggesting to use any arbitrary unit instead of the common ones? great! Try to interpret data in different scales such as "$x_i$ is 2.5 unicorns above the rainbow", what does that mean?

Comment: I appreciate a sense of humour, but  you should realise that I am not suggesting that meaningless units have meaning. All the quantities are well defined given data; they just behave differently for different shapes of distribution. See Cliff, A.D., Haggett, P. and Ord, J.K. 1986. _Spatial Aspects of Influenza Epidemics_. London: Pion for an example. I can't recall another at the moment, but presumably the OP has others, yet he never came back to the question! Scaling by mean and SD may be widely used, but that doesn't mean it's always a good idea.